# How to override service arguments during it's call

Tags: php, symfony

I have a class to generate CSV file by accepting the data it requires. I have declared this class as symfony service like,

`<service id="admin.csv_response" class="AdminBundle\Controller\CsvResponse" public="true">
        <argument key="$data">NULL</argument>
        <argument key="$fileName">export.csv</argument>
</service>`

I need to call this service from controller like,

`$this->get('admin.csv_response');`

How can I pass the values of $data and $fileName during this call by passing these as parameters so that it overrides the already given values?

I tried the following line, but it doesn't work.

`$this->get('admin.csv_response', ['sample data', 'xxx.csv']);`

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add 2 setter methods in your service instead of inject them via constructor:

```
setData(string $data){...};
setFileName(string $fileName){...};
```

and then call them:

```
$this->get('admin.csv_response')->setData(...)->setFileName(...);
```